# Android: read and write data to xml file

Tags: java, android, xml

Im very new do android and java development. Im creating an app that allows a user to create multiple and undefined amount of checklists and within each checklist the user can add an undefined amount of items. (Each checklist will have different items the user has added.) The checklists will be displayed in a listView on the MainActivity and the checklist items will be displayed in a listview in the checkListActivity.

The the checklists are created by the user entering a ListName into a EditText and presses the AddList Button which are on the MainActivity.

The items are added with a similar process but on the CheckListActivity.

To achieve this I think I need an xml file. It would look something like this.

```
<CheckLists>
  <CheckList>
    <ListName>Example CheckList 1</ListName>
    <Item>ExampleItem1</Item>
    <Item>ExampleItem2</Item>
    <Item>ExampleItem3</Item>
    <Item>ExampleItem4</Item>
    <Item>ExampleItem5</Item>
    <Item>ExampleItem6</Item>
  </CheckList>
    <CheckList>
    <ListName>Example CheckList 2</ListName>
    <Item>ExampleItem1</Item>
    <Item>ExampleItem2</Item>
    <Item>ExampleItem3</Item>
    <Item>ExampleItem4</Item>
    <Item>ExampleItem5</Item>
    <Item>ExampleItem6</Item>
  </CheckList>
    <CheckList>
    <ListName>Example CheckList 3</ListName>
    <Item>ExampleItem1</Item>
    <Item>ExampleItem2</Item>
    <Item>ExampleItem3</Item>
    <Item>ExampleItem4</Item>
    <Item>ExampleItem5</Item>
    <Item>ExampleItem6</Item>
  </CheckList>
    <CheckList>
    <ListName>Example CheckList 4</ListName>
    <Item>ExampleItem1</Item>
    <Item>ExampleItem2</Item>
    <Item>ExampleItem3</Item>
    <Item>ExampleItem4</Item>
    <Item>ExampleItem5</Item>
    <Item>ExampleItem6</Item>
  </CheckList>
 </CheckLists>
```

...And so on...

When the MainActivity loads I need the app to display the current CheckLists in the listview. When the user clicks on a listview item it takes them to the checkListActivity which displays the items for said CheckList in another listview.

How would I go about doing this?
Any advice, examples and comments are very much appreciated.

Comment: please attach the stack trace of the error your are facing.

Comment: an what is the problem? Do you have problems with xml marshalling and unmarshalling or what?

Comment: [Search well before posting a question](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1PRFC_enIN613IN613&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=read+write+xml+file+in+android&spell=1)

Comment: You can use SharedPreference to store your list data instead of xml file.